# How to set the song I am listening to as a custom message in Gtalk?

Tags: gmail, google-talk

For chatting purposes I use my Gmail chat. I know how to type custom messages in the chat but not how to set the music I listen to as a custom message.

I use Windows Media Player for listening to music.

Is there a way to set the song I am listening to as a custom message in Gmail chat?
If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Gmail/Gchat does not currently support this. To do this, you must use a client such as [Gtalk](http://www.google.com/talk/).

As per [Google's instructions](http://support.google.com/talk/answer/43426?hl=en), you can share your current music via Gtalk:

> **If you'd like to show your contacts what music you're listening to at that very moment, select Show current music track from the Available or Busy section of your status drop-down menu.**
>
> Your status will automatically update each time your supported music player starts a new song, listing the track name and artist information:
>
> If you stop your music, your status will display the default Available or Busy message.

The list of supported players is located [here](http://support.google.com/talk/answer/answer.py?answer=44269).

[image: Gtalk Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please edit your answer, with the way in which you do it in GTALK? It will be helpful to many.

Comment: Does it show the current music track to us also? My Windows media player is playing a song and I have selected the 'Show Current Music Track' option but the song is not shown to me. Only the 'available' is shown to me.